# Error uploading certificate to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to upload a certificate to IAM from my UNIX server to attached to a load balancer in AWS.

When I issue the command: iam-servercertupload -b new.server.cert.pem -k new.server.pem -s mysite.cert.com -v -d I get the following errror:

```
Unable to load version information for the running SDK: com/amazonaws/sdk/versionInfo.properties not found on classpath
Set parameter http.useragent = Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.0.1
Set parameter http.protocol.version = HTTP/1.1
Set parameter http.connection-manager.class = class org.apache.commons.httpclient.SimpleHttpConnectionManager
Set parameter http.protocol.cookie-policy = rfc2109
Set parameter http.protocol.element-charset = US-ASCII
Set parameter http.protocol.content-charset = ISO-8859-1
Set parameter http.method.retry-handler = org.apache.commons.httpclient.DefaultHttpMeth
```

I am running this command as a sudo user. There isn't much on the web regarding this error.
Has anyone ever experienced this problem before?

Comment: I am experiencing exactly the same issue. Did you found a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the versionInfo.properties will be set while you do `aws configure`. So, please make sure you have done the `aws configure` before you try to upload the certificate.

The following command worked for me to upload a certificate to IAM. 
`aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name MyCertName --certificate-body file://STAR.mydomain.com.pem --private-key file://https_keys.pem --certificate-chain file://chain.cer`